# Using object property with dot in If condition in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell from .Net world. I am trying to write some if statement like the blow

**#1**

```
if (((Get-Item $pf).Exist))
{
     $password = [xml]( Get-Content $pf)
}
```

**#2**

```
if (((Get-Item $pf) | Select-Object Exist))
{
     $password = [xml]( Get-Content $pf)
}
```

**#3**

```
$result=(Get-Item $pf).Exist
if($result)
{
     $password = [xml]( Get-Content $pf)
}
```

**Questions:**
Both **#2** and **#3** will work as expected, however, I am also expecting **#1** to work as in .Net, but it seems always evaluate to false, so the statement never get executed. I am a little confused here, can someone explain me why **#1** is not working as what I would expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are all wrong. It's **[Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.exists.aspx)**, not Exist.

Also I think you are up for disappointment, when you test your code when the file does NOT exist.

I think what you are looking for is

```
Test-Path $pf
```

Comment: Since he wants to get the contents of the item, you could also verify that it is a file. It's as simple as including `-PathType Leaf`.

Comment: Sorry, it's my typo, I means Exists actually, I used autocomplete in the console, but just typed this in the post by myself, so I missed the s at the end. 

I actually ended up using Test-Path to do my job. However, it's just my wish to understand better why the #1 doesn't work as expected, as clearly I am with some wrong assumption from .Net world.

Comment: @JackyYuan You've done more errors when you typed, and I have no way of telling which those are. "*Both #2 and #3 will work as expected, however, I am also expecting #1 to work as in .Net, but it seems always evaluate to false*". This is not the case with the examples you are given, when you change Exist to Exists. Simply speaking I cannot reproduce your results. It's really hard getting a question answered when you get the crucial part of the question wrong. I would advise to spend more time on getting the questions exactly right, before posting them.